# Can't login on my instagram app anymore, screen turns blank after login

Tags: instagram, login

I try logging into one of my Instagram accounts, the other one works just fine without any problems. On the desktop page I get:

> Confirm Your Info on the App
>
> Confirm your information using the Instagram app to try to get back to your account.

and nothing else. Nothing about any weird activities or my account being suspended or anything, the account still exists: https://www.instagram.com/haku_blue_bayou/. When I try to log in on my app, I get "couldn't refresh feed", then "loading" and then the screen turns black and stays like this (it's white if I disable the dark theme).

I tried: restarting my phone, deleting app cache and storage, uninstalling and reinstalling theapp uninstalling and reinstalling an older version of theapp trying it out on different devices (Sony Xperia XZ2, Google Nexus7), resetting my password through email and facebook-account, changingapppermissions so Instagram has access to my camera and storage.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about using a mobile app are off-topic. They might be on-topic in [android.se] or [apple.se].

Answer (score 1):

My Instagram account is doing exactly the same thing as your account. I hate to tell you, but mine has been doing this well over two months now. This all started when Instagram asked me to verify my identity by taking a facial scan where you have to turn your head right, left, and up.

I refuse to engage in intrusive nonsense such is that so I disabled my account for four or five days as I had read were the request for verification is removed if you disable your account for three days. But, you have to re-enable the account before seven days time or Instagram will permanently delete your account.

To re-enable an account all you have to do is sign-in to your account. So, after four or five days, I signed-in to my account so that it would not get disabled. Once I signed in, I was hoping that my account would be back to normal and that Instagram would no longer be asking me to verify my identity by taking a facial recognition test in order for me to access my account.

Well, I sure as heck did not win the pony because immediately after signing in I got the black screen just like you are getting. Thus, over the past ten or eleven weeks I have periodically checked to see if I could access my account. But, without fail, every time I have signed in I immediately get the could not refresh feed info coming up on the screen and two or three seconds later my screen becomes black and stays black.

If I can find an answer to solve this problem, then I will certainly come to this platform and tell you what I found.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it, but no one is going to like the answer. A friend of mine wanted to help and try it on his phone, so I gave him my password. The facial scan verification came up on his phone and he did that for me (I wouldn't want to do that myself, but he has a public account with pictures of himself anyways, so giving his face to Instagram isn't anything new). So now my account has his face and I can use my account again.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to install several old Versions of the instagram app, and finally succeeded to get the video selfie to work with Instagram version 178.1.0.37.123 from March 2021 (Android 9 device).

**Edit:** 178 crashed after the verification. Version 199.0.0.34.119 on an Android 10 device finally worked and the insta account is back.